# Understand prefix out-

Tags: prefixes

From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/out-?show=1&t=1382485238)

> out- in a manner that is greater, better, or more than something else.
>   in a manner that exceeds or surpasses and
>   sometimes overpowers or defeats. e.g outmaneuver>

Does *outmaneuver* literally mean that manoeuvre the opponents out?

How shall we explain *outset* (meaning beginning) and *outtake* then?

Comment: Your link to Merriam-Webster (note spelling) appears to lead to your own Stack Exchange profile page, for some reason. The fact that a prefix has one meaning in one subset of words does not necessarily mean it has that meaning always. In ‘outtake’, the meaning is obviously one of removal (taking something _out_ of something else), while in ‘outset’ it is one of movement away (from ‘to set out’, meaning to start a journey—the outset is then the start of the journey, thence just ‘start’ in general).

Comment: Could use a bit more. Come on, copy & paste isn't outside the rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have noticed that some words have more than one meaning.

> I am *going* to the beach.
>
> I am *going* to eat.

The same can go for parts of words like prefixes.

> outward  (towards the outside)
>
> outbid (to bid more than someone else)

Also, you may have noticed that when you put words together, or even standing a lone, they may have non-literal meanings. They may have meanings that just are.

> call out (to yell)
>
> put out (to douse a fire -or- to let an animal outside -or- to offer oneself)

See, you hit more than one with the last one.

Comment: ‘Call out’ also has at least one other common meaning: that of confronting someone with their own nonsense (“One of these days, somebody’s gonna call you out on all your BS!”).